# Interjecting a promise into a pre-existing function

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm looking at https://guides.codepath.com/nodejs/Control-flow#1-introduction:

```
// Consuming a promise API
let promise = fs.promise.readFile(__filename)
promise.then(result => {}, err => {})

// Returning promises
readFile(name) {
  return fs.promise.readFile(path.join(__dirname, name))
}
```

Regarding:

```
fs.promise.readFile
```

I'm familiar with fs.readfile (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), but what are the rules regarding interjecting a promise into a pre-existing function.

Comment: Are you asking how to use promises?

Comment: That page is old and weird and is not accurate.  The node.js `fs` library does not expose `fs.promise`, though it does expose `fs.promises` which are promisified versions of fs functions.  There is also `util.promisify` which converts callback style functions that use the `(err, value)` callback to promises.  Use better online resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the rules regarding interjecting a promise into a pre-existing function

You can use promise-based logic in any function.  There are no specific "rules" per se.  But, if you want the caller to know when your promise-based asynchronous operations are complete or if they had an error, then you MUST return the promise from your function so the caller can use `.then()` and `.catch()` to get access to completion, results or error.

`async` functions are a special type of function that always returns a promise and allows you to use `await` inside the function to simplify programming with promises.

In your code example in your question, it is `fs.promises.readFile`, not `fs.promise.readFile`.  `fs.promises` has new versions of many of the `fs` module functions that return a promise instead of using a plain callback.

Your code example should be:

```
// Returning promises
readFile(name) {
  return fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, name))
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought  fs.promises.readFile was a generic construct ..

Comment: @user1592380 - The whole `fs.promises` API is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).